# How to make a valid p12 file to be correctly imported by SecPKCS12Import

Tags: ios, openssl, rsa, pkcs#12

I've solved my previos problem of converting XML RSA private key to PEM file, but I run into another problem that I get null data when importing P12 private key. Following is my steps:

1. Convert PEM file to P12 file

   ```
   openssl> pkcs12 -export -in rsa.pem -inkey rsa.pem -out rsa.p12 -nocerts
   ```
2. Read P12 file to iOS project

   ```
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]    
                       pathForResource:@"MyPrivateKey" ofType:@"p12"];
   NSData *p12data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
   if (![self getPrivateKeyRef]) 
       RSAPrivateKey = getPrivateKeywithRawKey(p12data);
   ```
3. Import P12 Private Key

   ```
   SecKeyRef getPrivateKeywithRawKey(NSData *pfxkeydata)
   { 
       NSMutableDictionary * options = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];

       // Set the public key query dictionary
       //change to your .pfx  password here 
       [options setObject:@"MyPassword" forKey:(id)kSecImportExportPassphrase];

       CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);

       OSStatus securityError = SecPKCS12Import((CFDataRef) pfxkeydata,
                                                (CFDictionaryRef)options, &items);

       CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
       SecIdentityRef identityApp =
       (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict,
                                            kSecImportItemIdentity);
       //NSLog(@"%@", securityError);

       assert(securityError == noErr);
       SecKeyRef privateKeyRef;
       SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(identityApp, &privateKeyRef);

       return privateKeyRef;

   }
   ```

Thought there was no err(OSStatus value is 0), but the items array didn't get any identity data. I am wondering if i didn't get the correct p12 file format due to wrong OpenSSl usage. Has anyone successfully import p12 file? I've stuck in this problem for a couple of days, please give me advices if you got clues, thanks!

Hubert

Comment: About OpenSSL usage: 1) The input key will be surely not the same as your input certificate 2) doc says `-nocerts` will create no certificate at the output; did you try without it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got some tips from the internet, and following is the steps to get iOS acceptable p12 key and certification file:

1. convert XML to PEM
   Shell> compile XMLSpec2PEM.java
   Shell> XMLSpec2PEM rsa.xml
   save the output result to rsa.pem
       (borrow from [here](http://www.platanus.cz/blog/converting-rsa-xml-key-to-pem))
2. convert PEM to RSA Private Key
   OpenSSL> rsa -in rsa.pem -out rsaPrivate.key
3. Generate a certification request
   OpenSSL> req -new -key rsaPrivate.key -out rsaCertReq.crt
   (input some basic certification data)
4. Sign certification of the request
   OpenSSL> x509 -req -days 3650 -in rsaCertReq.crt -signkey rsaPrivate.key -out rsaCert.crt
5. Convert the certification file format to DER (iOS acceptable format)
   OpenSSL> x509 -outform der -in rsaCert.crt -out rsaCert.der
6. Generate PKCS12 Private key(iOS acceptable format)
   OpenSSL> pkcs12 -export -out rsaPrivate.pfx -inkey rsaPrivate.key -in rsaCert.crt

No further steps, files generated in step 5 and 6 now can be used in iOS!

reference of OpenSSL instructions:
http://blogs.yaclife.com/?tag=ios%E3%80%80seckeyref%E3%80%80raw%E3%80%80key%E3%80%80rsa%E3%80%803des

http://devsec.org/info/ssl-cert.html

Comment: Thanks for reporting back Hubert. That's a terribly roundabout way to convert an XML encoded private key to an internal representation, but it should be correct and I'm not sure if there is a more robust way (outside of writing the conversion routine in Objective C, of course). Oh, you may accept your own answers after a while!

Comment: I guess the answer would be yes. What I have done above is just use openssl command line tool to convert it to be a valid key format, so the operations are possible to be done with openssl api. I did not do this simply because I only need to do it once.

Comment: In my case, step 2 "convert PEM to RSA Private Key" produced the exact same output file as the input file. Nevertheless, the p12 file produced after following all the steps was exactly what I needed for my iOS app and finding this post was a huge help.

Comment: the one and only truly useful tip I found after several zillions hours of search. Thank you for your help. I was getting some EXC_BAD_ACCESS in SecKeyGetBlockSize and SecKeyRawSign, because the pkcs12 key file was generated without any certificate. I can't understand why a so-much-important matter is so-damn-hard to implement where it should clearly be facilitated for the sake of security issues.