# SHA256withRSA what does it do and in what order?

Tags: java, ios, cryptography, rsa, sha256

I'm a total newbie when it comes to cryptography and such things. I don't (and dont want to) know the details of the SHA256 and RSA. I "know" what they do, not how they do it, and for now that's enough.

I'm wondering what the "SHA256withRSA"-algorithm (if you can call it that) actually do and in what order. For example, does it hash the data with SHA256 and then encrypts it using RSA or is it vice-versa, or something else?

The reason I'm asking is because I wanna do the java equivalent of:

```
Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA")
signature.initSign(privateKey); //privateKey == a key extracted from a .p12 file
```

in Objective-C on iOS. And I couldn't seem to find any stuff that does exactly this, therefore I'm asking, can I just hash the data (SHA256) and then encrypt it (RSA) (or vice-versa) and get the same behavior?

What is the suggested solution for doing this kind of thing?

Thank you!

EDIT:
I failed to mention that I sign the data using a private key that is obtained by doing:

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keystore.load(new FileInputStream(new File(filename)), password.toCharArray());
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
```

Where filename is for example: "/somewhere/mykey.p12".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Definition of SHA256withRSA

`"SHA256withRSA"` implements the PKCS#1 v1.5 padding and modular exponentiation with the formal name [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2) after calculating the hash over the data using SHA256.

### Signature generation

The general strategy for signature generation is:

1. **hashing the message;**
2. **padding the hash for signature generation;**
3. conversion of the previous result to a number using OS2IP;
4. **modular exponentiation using the **private** exponent and the modulus;**
5. conversion of the previous result to an octet string using I2OSP.

### Signature verification

The strategy for signature verification consists of two parts.

Part 1:

1. **hashing;**
2. **padding the hash using the same method used for signature generation;**

The result of part 1 is the locally generated padded hash (called EM').

Part 2:

1. conversion of the signature to a number using OS2IP;
2. **modular exponentiation using the **public** exponent and the modulus;**
3. conversion of the previous result to an octet string using I2OSP.

The result of part 2 is the original padded hash (called EM).

Finally the original and local padded hashes (EM and EM') are compared; the signature verifies if the comparison succeeds.

### Notes

- The PSS scheme in PKCS#1 v2.0 onward has been designed to provide a non-deterministic scheme with a better security proof for the padding. For new protocols it is advisable to use the PSS scheme instead, although the PKCS#1 v1.5 scheme is still considered secure.
- The modular exponentiation during signature generation may not use the private exponent; it quite often uses the Chinese Remainder Theorem if the CRT parameters are present for a ~4x speedup.
- OS2IP converts an octet string (or byte array) to an integer by interpreting it as a statically sized unsigned big endian value, I2OSP performs the reverse operation. If the runtime can directly perform big integer calculations on the binary representation then the conversion is implicit (i.e. doesn't need to be performed at all).
- The PKCS#1 v1.5 padding used for encryption and signature generation is different, so using encryption may result in erroneous signatures.
- An alternative verification method is to extract the hash from the padding and perform a compare of the hash values.

---

### PKCS#1 v1.5 for iOS

With regards to the padding in iOS, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5066573/589259) by Thomas Pornin. Basically you should create the SHA-256 hash, prefix a static block of data (defined in the PKCS#1 specifications) then use `SecKeyRawSign` using `kSecPaddingPKCS1`.

For your convenience, the PKCS#1 defined block of data that needs to be prefixed in hex notation for SHA-256 (it can be bit hard to find in the standard documents, it's in the notes of [section 9.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-9.2)):

```
30 31 30 0D 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01 05 00 04 20
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer! I failed to mention that the file that contains the private key that is used is a .p12 file, and in my understanding uses PKCS12, what difference would that make? (I will edit my question to contain this information)

Comment: The container format should not make a difference regarding the signature, so this is a bit of an additional question. Please check if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025807/how-to-make-a-valid-p12-file-to-be-correctly-imported-by-secpkcs12import contains the information you require.

Comment: Thank you! You have answered the question I asked and will accept your answer. The link you provided helped me a bit, but I'm still at a loss how I should use the key in obj-c to sign data. Any pointers? Or should I start a new question? Thank you again!

Comment: Isn't the returned key reference the first input of the sign method? If this isn't true, then browse around through available code a bit. You may of course always ask a new question (although I'm not an iOS developer, so I may not be able to answer myself).