# Java Implementation of RSA Signature using RSAwithSHA256

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature

I want to sign a message using RSA private key. This message will be verified by someone else maybe using another programming language other than Java.

I will use the java.security.Signature class to sign the messsage.
The code will be :

```
Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
privateSignature.initSign(key); //RSA private key
privateSignature.update(text.getBytes("UTF8")); //text is the clear text string

byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();

return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
```

When I check the result and used the publickey to decrypt the signature, I found that padding bytes are added before the SHA256 digest.

My Question is : is the resulted signature generated in a standard way so that it can be verified with the public key in widely used programming languages or is it java specific?

Comment: The padding used by `SHA256withRSA` is [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#section-8.2) and described in RFC 8017. It is a standard and the signature can be verified cross-platform (i.e. not only in Java), for details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21019504/9014097).

Comment: Thank you Topaco, your comment answered my question.