# iOS RSA Decryption

Tags: ios, objective-c, rsa

I'm using this website to generate public and private key
http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/ and I'm trying to figure it out how to create SecKeyRef from the private key

I've found this [project](https://github.com/reejosamuel/RSA) which looks very promising but it doesn't work for me.

Here is my code which try to create the SecKeyRef

```
 NSString* publicKey = @"MIGeMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GMADCBiAKBgHKzKc/6vphvntLiP1r/YvxjSLolPeDeOCy48ao5ymwNU2Nqbfeir/qHqbqSAhclAO8TGq8QIpE5ObAKNp2j01pu8Cu9AqwdtZ6EZa/NYahfITKS8iYGs6cHzk2LGw8AqFOEJqHrW/xR8MOS1J765KeZOBCSrWZ5Ag/lpb5jxiDlAgMBAAE=";
    [[RSA sharedInstance] setPublicKey:publicKey];
```

and

```
- (BOOL)setPublicKey: (NSString *)keyAsBase64 {

    NSData *extractedKey =
                [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:keyAsBase64 options:0];

    /* Load as a key ref */
    OSStatus error = noErr;
    CFTypeRef persistPeer = NULL;

    NSData * refTag = [self.serverPublicIdentifier dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableDictionary * keyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [keyAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [keyAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [keyAttr setObject:refTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];

    /* First we delete any current keys */
    error = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) keyAttr);

    [keyAttr setObject:extractedKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    [keyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnPersistentRef];

    error = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) keyAttr, (CFTypeRef *)&persistPeer);

    if (persistPeer == nil || ( error != noErr && error != errSecDuplicateItem)) {
        NSLog(@"Problem adding public key to keychain");
        return FALSE;
    }

    CFRelease(persistPeer);

    serverPublicRef = nil;

    /* Now we extract the real ref */
    [keyAttr removeAllObjects];
    /*
     [keyAttr setObject:(id)persistPeer forKey:(id)kSecValuePersistentRef];
     [keyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)kSecReturnRef];
     */
    [keyAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [keyAttr setObject:refTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [keyAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [keyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnRef];

    // Get the persistent key reference.
    error = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keyAttr, (CFTypeRef *)&serverPublicRef);

    if (serverPublicRef == nil || ( error != noErr && error != errSecDuplicateItem)) {
        NSLog(@"Error retrieving public key reference from chain");
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

I'm getting `serverPublicRef == nil` but the error is 0 (which is ok.)

Answer (score 0):

The `kSecClassKey` does not have a `kSecValueData` field. You should look into using [`SecPKCS12Import()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157-CH1g-SW35).

Some related questions:

- [How to create private key from file in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902653/how-to-create-private-key-from-file-in-objective-c/16862255#16862255)
- [How to make a valid p12 file to be correctly imported by SecPKCS12Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025807/how-to-make-a-valid-p12-file-to-be-correctly-imported-by-secpkcs12import)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, can you please explain a little bit more on what and how do i need to do with this method ?

Comment: I’m not sure how much information you need. So I added some links to some other questions about SecPKCS12Import.